# Can not save to "txt file" like "run" result

Tags: python, twitter, web-scraping, web-crawler

When I run the code,

I want to save it as output.

But my code is stored differently.

How do I fix it? Thank you for your advice.

"run result" =

1 : {'text': 'Today is sunday! https//abcd'}

2 : {'text': 'hi!!!\nhi!!!\nhi!!! https//abcd}

"Text file saving result"=

Today is sunday! https//abcd

hi!!!

hi!!!

hi!!! https//abcd

```
import tweepy
import time
import os
import json
import simplejson


search_term = ''



lat = ""
lon = ""
radius = ""


API_key = ""
API_secret = ""
Access_token = ""
Access_token_secret = ""

location = "%s,%s,%s" % (lat, lon, radius)
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(API_key, API_secret)
auth.set_access_token(Access_token, Access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

c=tweepy.Cursor(api.search,
                q="{}".format(search_term),
                rpp=100,
                geocode=location,
                include_entities=False)

wfile = open("test1.txt", mode='w', encoding='utf8')
data = {}
i = 1
for tweet in c.items():

    data['text'] = tweet.text
    print(i, ":", data)
    wfile.write(data['text']+'\n')
    time.sleep(0.35)
    i += 1

wfile.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to clarify your question, i guess nobody really knows what you want to achieve exactly. Do you want a "json like" output of a dictionary in your text file? Give us an example, how your file's content should look like.

I give a guess, maybe you just want the string represenation of your dict, you get the string representation by calling `str(data)` or `data.__str__()`.

```
wfile = open("test1.txt", mode='w', encoding='utf8')
data = {}
i = 1
for tweet in c.items():

    data['text'] = tweet.text
    print(i, ":", data)
    wfile.write(str(data) +'\n')
    time.sleep(0.35)
    i += 1

wfile.close()
```